Why can't I correctly generate coronal and sagittal sections from a vector of 256 CT images using my C++ code?
Loading 256 CT cross-sectional slices of 512x512, and placing them in a vector<cv::Mat>(256). Now I want to get coronal sections and sagittal sections. I did this:
// Get coronal section slice  
std::vector<cv::Mat> get_coronal() {  
    std::vector<cv::Mat> coronal_section(slice_height, cv::Mat(slice_num, slice_width, CV_16UC1, cv::Scalar(0)));  
    for (int i = 0; i < slice_height; i++)  
    {  
        for (int k = 0; k < slice_num; k++)  
        {  
            pixel_array[k].row(i).copyTo(coronal_section[i].row(k));  
        }  
    }  
    return coronal_section;  
}  
  
// Get sagittal section slice  
std::vector<cv::Mat> get_sagittal() {  
    std::vector<cv::Mat> sagittal_section(slice_width, cv::Mat(slice_height, slice_num, CV_16UC1, cv::Scalar(0)));  
    for (int j = 0; j < slice_width; j++)  
    {  
        for (int k = 0; k < slice_num; k++)  
        {  
            pixel_array[k].col(j).copyTo(sagittal_section[j].col(k));  
        }  
    }  
    return sagittal_section;  
}

//get transverse section slice
std::vector<cv::Mat> get_transverse()
{
    return pixel_array;
}

I used imshow to display the cross-sectional, coronal, and sagittal planes, but the coronal and sagittal planes could not be displayed properly. I tried adjusting their vector data types to CV_8UC1, but the results were even worse:
.
After changing the two functions to initialize the vector<cv::Mat>(256)  differently, the images are shown correctly:
std::vector<cv::Mat> get_coronal() {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> coronal_section(slice_width);
    for (int i = 0; i < slice_width; i++) {
        cv::Mat slice(slice_num, slice_height, CV_16UC1);
        for (int j = 0; j < slice_num; j++) {
            pixel_array[j].row(i).copyTo(slice.row(j));
        }
        coronal_section[i] = slice;
    }
    return coronal_section;
}

std::vector<cv::Mat> get_sagittal() {
    std::vector<cv::Mat> sagittal_section(slice_height);
    for (int i = 0; i < slice_height; i++) {
        cv::Mat slice(slice_width,slice_num , CV_16UC1);
        for (int j = 0; j < slice_num; j++) {
            pixel_array[j].col(i).copyTo(slice.col(j));
        }
        sagittal_section[i] = slice;
    }
    return sagittal_section;
}


Why do the two ways of initializing  lead to different results?

for debugging purposes, I'd recommend swapping the file reading with synthetic data. just, say, a handful of tiny images, with easy to recognize data (give each voxel a specific number that reveals its indices, like decimal 444 for voxel at i=4, j=4, k=4. then you can know if the code does the right thing in principle.

i think the first attempt and the second attempt had no difference, but why the first one didnt work, i dont know

In your first attempt, you create the output array with:
std::vector<cv::Mat> sagittal_section(slice_width, cv::Mat(slice_height, slice_num, CV_16UC1, cv::Scalar(0)));  

This code creates one cv::Mat object, then populates a vector with copies of that object. But these copies all share their pixel data. Each of those copies is the same image. If you change a pixel value in one, you change it in all of them.
Thus, when you write in the loop to
sagittal_section[j].col(k), only the last j iteration is evident, all earlier iterations wrote to the same column, their work was overwritten.
The second attempt is the right way to do it, creating a new image for each output vector element.
In OpenCV, when you want to create a copy of an image that you can modify independently, you cannot do im2 = im1, as the two will share their pixel data. Instead, do im2 = im1.clone(). See this Q&A. And std::vector essentially uses = to populate all the vector elements.
